# How to keep div from overlapping on resolution re-size without overflow?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make these div element tables not overlap without the use of the [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property. I am aware I could increase the height of the div boxes but I would like for the div element to be flexible so one div would stay stacked on-top of the other regardless of screen resolution. Any thoughts?

CSS:

```
 .tbl_box2 {
   display: inline-flex;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;  
  }

  .table2 {
   width: 25%;
   height: 315px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.5);         
  }

  .table3 {
   width: 75%;
   height: 315px;
   vertical-align: center;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "tbl_box2">
          <table class = "table2">
            <tr>
               <td><img style="display:block;" width="100%" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/retriever.png" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class = "table3">
            <tr>
              <th><h2>The domestic dog</h2> <i>(Canis lupus familiaris)</i></th>
            </tr>
              <tr>
               <td style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                <p>
                  The domestic dog has been selectively bred for millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, and physical attributes.
                 </p>
                 <p>
                  Being the oldest domesticated animals, their long association with people has allowed dogs to be uniquely attuned to human behavior, as well as thrive on a starch-rich diet which would be inadequate for other canid species.
                 </p>
                 <p>
                  Dogs perform many roles for people, such as hunting, herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and military, companionship, and, more recently, aiding handicapped individuals. This impact on human society has given them the nickname "man's best friend" in the Western world.
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class = "tbl_box2">
          <table class = "table2">
            <tr>
               <td><img style="display:block;" width="100%" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/retriever.png" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class = "table3">
            <tr>
              <th><h2>The domestic dog</h2> <i>(Canis lupus familiaris)</i></th>
            </tr>
              <tr>
               <td style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                <p>
                  The domestic dog has been selectively bred for millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, and physical attributes.
                 </p>
                 <p>
                  Being the oldest domesticated animals, their long association with people has allowed dogs to be uniquely attuned to human behavior, as well as thrive on a starch-rich diet which would be inadequate for other canid species.
                 </p>
                 <p>
                  Dogs perform many roles for people, such as hunting, herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and military, companionship, and, more recently, aiding handicapped individuals. This impact on human society has given them the nickname "man's best friend" in the Western world.
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class = "tbl_box2">
          <table class = "table2">
            <tr>
               <td><img style="display:block;" width="100%" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/retriever.png" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class = "table3">
            <tr>
              <th><h2>The domestic dog</h2> <i>(Canis lupus familiaris)</i></th>
            </tr>
              <tr>
               <td style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                <p>
                  The domestic dog has been selectively bred for millennia for various behaviors, sensory capabilities, and physical attributes.
                 </p>
                 <p>
                  Being the oldest domesticated animals, their long association with people has allowed dogs to be uniquely attuned to human behavior, as well as thrive on a starch-rich diet which would be inadequate for other canid species.
                 </p>
                 <p>
                  Dogs perform many roles for people, such as hunting, herding, pulling loads, protection, assisting police and military, companionship, and, more recently, aiding handicapped individuals. This impact on human society has given them the nickname "man's best friend" in the Western world.
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to use `flexbox` & tables here...or divs & tables. I'd pick a layout method and stick to it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still learning CSS and am not really sure what works together yet. Thanks for the input though! I'll keep it in mind for future reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can use set height of element in percentage % instead of pixels. When you will use % for css it will consider it relatively to resolution of screen. or you can change height parameter to auto.

> height:auto

Text is overflow for each table because you have set less size for outer div compare to inner div. I have applied some changes in css. Check if this found useful for you.

```
 .tbl_box2 {
   display: inline-flex;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;  
  }

  .table2 {
   width: 25%;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgba(153,153,153,0.5);         
  }

  .table3 {
   width: 75%;
   height: auto;
   vertical-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, fantastic work! I cannot believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much for the help! .